# iptable ip_conntrack_max testing

Tags: linux, firewalls, ddos, iptables

I was trying to understand how `ip_conntrack_max` works so i have created two VM and set ip_conntrack_max to 10000

I used `hping` to open 10000 udp connection on VM using following command

`hping --udp --rand-source 10.10.10.1 -p 111 -i u10`

I have seen after 1 min `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_count` get full and it was stuck at 10000

but still i can ssh on machine and connect to that port from remote machine..

why i didn't get error in /var/log/messages saying following?

`ip_conntrack: table full, dropping packet`

am i doing something wrong in test?